# Selecting rows from 2d numpy array given a condition from a function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, filter

I see a lot of examples using `np.where()` that work well when given the following:

```
x = np.array([...])
w = np.where(x > 5)
```

What if I need to filter the elements based on a function, like this?

```
a = [..]
b = filter(lambda x: is_true(x), a)
```

I would like to be able to do this filter function directly in numpy, but i can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Could you add a sample case?

Comment: I want to filter out each element where is_true(element) == False efficiently.

Comment: And `is_true` is some custom function?

Comment: Correct. I am implementing a non-maximal suppression but the difference between my use case and others that I've seen on stack overflow is that I need the overlap to be between both bounding boxes.

In other words- implementations i see on stackoverflow only take one side into account. I care about the actual intersection between the two bounding boxes, not just whether one is bigger and swallows the other by more than some ratio.

Comment: I see, so for true vectorization that is meant for performance, we would need to vectorize that func implementation itself.

Comment: I've tried that out as well:

`code`
f = np.vectorize(myfunc)
f(arr)
`code`

The problem I'm running into now is that my array has a shape of (x,4) where 4 are the coordinates of the bounding box. The function seems to be getting run over over single coordinate separately and I don't see a way to specify the axis anywhere.

Comment: `np.vectorize` isn't true vectorization and isn't meant for performance. See if you can use ufuncs and since you are talking about overlaps, [`numpy strides`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) could help too if you decide to vectorize the func itself so that it works on larger chunks of data if not entire data.